# Design approach for a SQL query builder with Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, optimization

In my webapp I need to create a query engine module where the user selects in the view what columns and filters he want and get the datas related to these queries.

So, I have to build SQL dynamic queries with this kind of format :
`SELECT {columns} FROM MainTable FULL OUTER JOIN SecondTable ON ... FULL OUTER JOIN ThirdTable ON ... WHERE {filters}`

The columns and filters are known at runtime. (read-only)

Actually, I have a big SQL Server view (Mapped entity in Java) which make 3 FULL OUTER JOIN of others SQL server views. And I build the query in the source code by parsing keywords as AND, OR, number, date, text, ...
Finally, I return a response in the front-end module a table with datas.

But, I'm facing performance issues (scalability) with this method and I'm looking for a more efficient way to do that.

Is it possible to split the SELECT query mentionned above in subqueries to improve performances ? Or there is better design approach for that ?

---

Here the request I actually use (names changed) with **Hibernate** :

```
SELECT * FROM BigView "+WHERE+" OPTION(ROBUST PLAN)
```

*(BigView is aggregation of 4 views : RootTable, Table2, Table3, Table4)*

Btw, I know `"+WHERE+"` is a bad practice but this is not the concern of this topic

I thought using this instead (delete BigView in SQL Server and the related entity) but it actually does same thing even if there is a little performance gain with the columns restriction :

```
SELECT     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rownum, tmp.* FROM ( SELECT  '' AS id, "+columns+" "+
                        "FROM RootTable FULL OUTER JOIN "+
                        "Table2 ON RootTable.RT_ID = Table2.RT_N FULL OUTER JOIN "+
                        "Table3 ON RootTable.RT_ID = Table3.RT_ID FULL OUTER JOIN "+
                        "Table4 ON RootTable.RT_ID = Table4.RT_N "+
                        WHERE+" ) AS tmp
```

---

My previous deleted question was not enough focused so I hope this one is correct.

EDIT : I add this filter (WHERE clause) to show what can be requested for example :
`RT_ID>'10' AND   (  Table2_Topic LIKE '%test%' OR  Table3_Date=CONVERT(datetime, '24/09/2020', 103) OR   (   Table3_N is not null and Table2_ID<>0 ) )`

Comment: If you are looking for performance enhancement, might I suggest using Spark? It has inbuilt operations that resemble SQL queries and is easily scalable.

Comment: Usually the worst performance in a SQL query comes from OR, IN() and other conditions that force the engine to run through one or more entire tables without using indexes. If you have dynamic views, the same happens in their conditions. Also joining to tables without proper indexes is a problem. Outer joins are not super fast either.

Comment: @ParthPandya I'm not aware of Spark I'll check that if it can solve something. I heard about Presto as well, but I thought there was a easier solution

Comment: @drkblog The format of the views doesn't change or rarely. But, the BigView is anyway consuming a big time execution cause of the large numbers of rows and columns. The solution could be to filter each view before the join. And, it's mandatory to use Outer joins in my case because I need to perform the search on all columns from these views.

Comment: @OFFEN Yeah, I assumed you needed the outers. Your views must be optimized because you won't get any better performance after including a view in a new query. But you said you could leave views alone. Then you face a big challenge, which is your query changes and optimizing in SQL is very query dependant.If there is no limit for the user I don't see how you could optimize. You should add indexes to all the columns, which is mindless. You can use EXPLAIN sql command to get information about a query and see why it is slow. But again, in a per-query basis.